# Object serialization probelm

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I show you the following simplified codes to try to explain my problem:

**index.php**

```php
<?php
session_start();
include ('class.php');
$a =  new A();
$_SESSION['serializedClass'] = serialize($a);
?>
<div id="result"></div><br><br><input type="button" id="btn" value="populate div">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "#btn" ).click(function() {  
$.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {  
                                   $('#result').html(data);
                                 }

      });
});
});
</script>
```

**ajax.php**

```php
<?php
session_start();
include ('class.php');
$a = unserialize($_SESSION['serializedClass']);
print $a->managestr();
?>
```

class.php:

```php
class A
{ 
    public $startProcess;
    public $strCreated = false;
    public $str;
    public function __construct()
    {  
        $this->startProcess = time();
    }
    public function setstr($currStr)
    {    
        if (!$this->strCreated) $this->strCreated = true;
        $this -> str = 'Start process at '.$this->startProcess.': '.$currStr;

    }
    public function managestr()
    {
      if ($this->strCreated) return $this->str; 
      $currStr = 'here at '.time();
      if (!$this->strCreated) $this->setstr($currStr);
      return $this -> str;              
    }
}
```

In the `index.php` page I serialize the instance of the class and I store it in a `SESSION` variable in order to reuse the same instance in every ajax call.

What I expect, when I click "populate div" button, is to see a result like this:

FIRST CLICK:
`Start process 1577113743: here at 1577113743`

SECOND CLICK:
`Start process 1577113743: here at 1577113743`

i.e. the same result after first click because I always stored the value in `$this -> str`, indeed if it is created I should get the stored value.

Actually, when I click second time or more, I see:

```sh
Start process 1577113743: here at 1577113744
Start process 1577113743: here at 1577113745, etc
```

I can't understand why I lost the stored value at first click.

Answer (score 0):

When serializing an object, PHP only stores the object's current state, i.e. its property values. It does not serialize its methods.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you. Would there be a different way to get the desired result ? Using the same instance of a class in an ajax call, as well as my example.

Comment: Maybe you can only store the values in the `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but I was looking for an alternative solution to not load $_SESSION. I will try to reconsider this idea, thank you.